# Mysql index didn't take effect

Tags: mysql

I'm working with `mysql-5.7.16`

Here's my table

```
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id             | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| account_id     | varchar(45)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| account_name   | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| bm_id          | varchar(45)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| type           | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | 0                 |                             |
| account_status | smallint(4)      | YES  |     | 0                 |                             |
| submitter      | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| submit_time    | timestamp        | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                             |
| status         | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | 0                 |                             |
| create_time    | timestamp        | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                             |
| update_time    | timestamp        | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| is_delete      | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | 0                 |                             |
| apply_id       | varchar(32)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| urgent         | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | 0                 |                             |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+


CREATE TABLE `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bm_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `account_status` smallint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `submitter` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `submit_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `create_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `update_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `is_delete` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `apply_id` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `urgent` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `condition` (`is_delete`,`submit_time`,`submitter`,`status`,`urgent`,`type`,`account_id`,`account_name`,`bm_id`,`account_status`,`apply_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

I want to use `index` condition and speed my query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * 
FROM `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle` 
WHERE
(`ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle`.`is_delete` = 0
AND `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle`.`status` IN (0, 1, 2, 3) 
AND `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle`.`submit_time` >= "1970-01-01 00:00:00" 
AND `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle`.`submit_time` <= "2021-03-26 11:54:00" 
AND `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle`.`submitter` LIKE  "%23123%" 
AND `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle`.`submitter` IN ("111@dd.com")
AND `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle`.`urgent` IN (0, 1) 
AND `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle`.`type` IN (0, 1, 2, 3) 
ORDER BY `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle`.`submit_time` DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

But index seems not taking effect:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                          | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle | all  | condition     | null      | null    | null   | 230361| Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
```

And if i change

```
 `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle`.`submit_time` >= "1970-01-01 00:00:00" 
AND `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle`.`submit_time` <= "2021-03-26 11:54:00"
```

to

```
`ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle`.`submit_time` BETWEEN "1970-01-01 00:00:00"  AND "2021-03-26 11:54:00"
```

the  result become

```
+----+-------------+--------------------------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                          | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle | ref  | condition     | condition | 2       | const | 230361 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
```

Why the the condition changed  and What should I do to optimize my query?

Thanks .

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html and do you see an improvement when you try hinting?

Comment: Only a prefix `is_delete,submit_time` may work for your query (really only `is_delete` is used - see "key_len"). `LIKE '%pattern'` cannot use index. Use index by ```(`is_delete`, `status`, `urgent`, `type`, `submit_time`)```. PS. `submitter` cannot be `IN ("111@dd.com")` and `LIKE  "%23123%"` at the same time.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for your reply,  as conditions in where clause showed,  can you give me some advise to speed up my query, thanks

Comment: How many possible separate values does each separate column in `is_delete`, `status`, `urgent`, `type` contains? What condition from 2 used must be applied for `submitter`? What conditions in your query are absolutely static (never changes from query to query)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that the Optimizer did not pick

```
KEY `condition` (`is_delete`,`submit_time`, ...)
```

It would have used both of those columns both for the `WHERE` filtering and the `ORDER BY`.

Which of these do you need?

```
AND `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle`.`submitter` LIKE  "%23123%" 
AND `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle`.`submitter` IN ("111@dd.com")
```

(With both those clauses, you will get no rows in the resultset; the `EXPLAIN` possibly realizes this, making the `EXPLAIN` output useless.)

If it is the `IN(one-item)`, I recommend adding

```
INDEX(is_delete, submitter,   -- first, in this order
      urgent, type, status,   -- next, in any order
      submit_time)            -- range last
```

Even if you sometimes put multiple items in that `IN`, this index may be useful.

Avoid "index hints"; such may "help today, but hurt tomorrow".

Re IN and optimization:

- `col IN (one-item)` is the same as `col = one-item` and the optimizer is smart enough to optimize them the same way
- `col IN (1, 2)` is harder to optimize that a single choice.
- If the `IN` list lists all possible values, then you are better off removing the `AND IN (...)`.  However, this may necessitate a different index.  For example, if your query can thus be simplified to

  ```
    WHERE `is_delete` = 0
      AND `submit_time` >= "1970-01-01 00:00:00" 
      AND `submit_time` <= "2021-03-26 11:54:00" 
      AND `submitter` = "111@dd.com"
    ORDER BY ``submit_time` DESC
  ```

Then this is optimal:

```
INDEX(is_delete, submitter,   -- in either order
      submit_time)
```

In that case it will look at no more than 20 rows to handle `LIMIT 10,10`.  Otherwise, it will probably look at lots of rows, sort them, skip 10, and deliver 10.

Comment: There's one more question about this table. The `count(id)` query is too slow. It cost me about `3s`. Can you give me soem advise to speed it ?

Comment: @jiaJimmy - `COUNT(id)` requires testing `id` for `NOT NULL` to decide whether to "count the row".  `COUNT(*)` is the usual way to simply say "count all the rows".  This change _may_ speed it up.  (There are cases where it makes no noticeable difference.)